# Error while providing the condition for if Statement

Tags: php

```
$h = 30;
$flipSum = $h - 1;

if (5 < print $flipSum) {
echo "Yes";
}
else {
echo "No";
}
```

The output of this file is "29No". Where is the error? I want the output to be "Yes".

**Also,** I'm getting errors when I remove $h and $flipSum and replace it using one variable like below. How do i go about with the bracketing?

```
$h = 30;

if (1 < print $h - 1) {
echo "s";
}
else {
echo "Sa";
}
```

This is giving the same output "29No".

Thank you,
Sai

Comment: HINT: what's the **print** doing ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The opening statement to your conditional should be:

```
if (5 < $flipSum) {
```

What you *want* is to evaluate `5 < $flipSum`, where `$flipSum` is presumably some number. What you're *actually* doing is evaluating `5 < print $flipSum` – where the return value of `print $flipSum` is [*always* **`1`**](http://www.php.net/print). Therefore, you are seeing `No` as the returned value.

**More info**: the reason the return value is `29No` is because – in `5 < print $flipSum` – **two** things are happening (in order):

1. The value of `$flipSum` is being printed – hence `29`
2. The entire conditional is evaluated (to `false`) and the corresponding block is entered – hence `No`

Answer (score 1):

print statement in PHP returns 1 always.. That's why you were getting No as the output

More about print:
http://www.php.net/print

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `print` construct in your `if` logic as it always returns `1`:

```
$h = 30;
$flipSum = $h - 1;

if (5 < $flipSum) {
  echo "{$flipSum}Yes";
} else {
  echo "{$flipSum}No";
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me if `{}` only puts value of variable or we can perform arithmetic as well? Like `echo "{$h-1}Yes";`

Comment: No, you cannot perform arithemetics there, I just always encase variables into `{}` for better readability.